# Convert number to BigInt or String when it's value exceeds Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER in ECMAScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

When we don't know the numerical value at advance, can we convert it to BigInt or String without value corruption?

```
const targetNumber: number = 90071992547409946; // suppose we don't know it in advance
function splitEach3DigitsGroupWithComma(targetNumber: number | bigint | string): string {
  if(targetNumber > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) {
    // targetNumber = BigInt(targetNumber); // 90071992547409952n
    // targetNumber = String(targetNumber); // 90071992547409950
    // We need to do something before proceed!
  }

  return String(targetNumber).replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/gu, ",");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `targetNumber` is neither already a BigInt nor a string at the point where you first can work with it, then it's a plain number - and in that case, it may only be as precise as a number can be, per the IEEE 754 standard. If you only have a `number` to work with to begin with, possible more precise values have *already* been lost earlier.

To maintain precision, ensure that the value stays as a BigInt or string from beginning to end. If it gets converted to a `number` at any time in between, and then that number gets used, it may have lost precision, depending on the number.

In other words, to do something like this, you need to *start with* something like

```
const targetNumber = '90071992547409946';
```

or

```
const targetNumber = 90071992547409946n;
```

It can't be done in the middle of the process, once you already only have a `number`, while maintaining precision.

Answer (score 1):

If your number is bigger than `Number._MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` then you can not safely convert into `BigInt` as is.

Say your big integer is `134640597783270600` which is > `Number._MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. If you do like

```
>  n = 134640597783270600;

>  BigInt(n);
<- 134640597783270592n // Wrong..!
```

So  you should first check if `n` is bigger than `Number._MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` and if so just convert it to string first

```
>  BigInt(n > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER ? n+"" : n);
<- 134640597783270600n // Correct..!
```

However, if `n` happens to be a big integer expressed in the exponential form like `7.576507751994453e+29` then this happens;

```
>  BigInt(7.576507751994453e+29+"");
   Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot convert 7.576507751994453e+29 to a BigInt
    at BigInt (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

At this time i think to be on the safe side, it's best to convert all those integers greater than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` into `String` type first to test for exponential representation. So, despite we have a `BigInt` constructor in JS, apparently we still need a function.

```
function toBigInt(n){
  return n.toString().includes("e") ? BigInt(n)
                                    : BigInt(n+"");
}
```